# JS, jQuery: Select element directly above script that is asking for it?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am making a price element, in the form of an P. It will be put inside of a Java Server Tag (JST). I will be generating multiple of these. The goal of this element is to be able to pass a number into the tag, and display the number as a price. I will read the value and replace it with the price value, using the span element directly above the script.

I have tried, and nothing has worked. I have googled bunches of answers, and I have found little help.

---

#### Question 1

**My question is, how can I exclusively select the above span element via js or jQuery.**
I cant do the "select by class" method, or the "select by tag method" because there could be another span, or another price tag element with the same class that the script could get confused with.

**I am wondering if there is a way to select the closest class, or tag     to the script that is asking for it, in order to identify the       element, or if there is some other way to do it?**

...

#### Question 2

**My second question is, if that is not possible, is there a way to pas a JS DOM element into a java server tag?**

```html
<!--Somewhere in the pages header tag-->
<script>
    function formatToMoney(number) {
      return (number).toLocaleString('en-US', {
        style: 'currency',
        currency: 'USD',
      });
</script>
<!-- ------------------------------ --->

<!--Java server tag element-->

<p>Price:

  <span>5</span>
  <script>
    /*Here... i need to be able to acess the span above exclusively via Jquery and/or JS
    The span must be acessable only by the script directly below it
    (i will be making clones of this exact P tag)*/
    }
  </script>

</p>

<!-- --------------------- --->
```

Comment: This does not seem like the best way to approach this.  You will be redefining `function formatToMoney(number)` A LOT.  And there are cleaner and easier ways to achieve what you're [I think] you're trying.

Comment: I know, I don't really have any better ideas, though... @Marc

Comment: Provide us with more HTML structure and let us help you solve this.

Comment: Even using an H1 for this feels wrong - is the price really a _top level_ heading? This also seems like the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) ... you are trying to solve some problem X and you _think_ the solution is Y, so you are asking us about Y when there is probably a better solution to X.

Comment: sorry, I need to clarify that I was only using an H1 tag as an example. @StephenP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `document.currentScript` to get the current executing script element. After retrieving the element you can use `previousElementSibling` to select the element sibling right before the script(span in this case).

```
<span>
  Hi
</span>
<script>
(() => {
  const script = document.currentScript;
  
  if (script != null) {
    const span = script.previousElementSibling;
  }
})();
</script>
```

As others have stated this is a pretty bad idea and is going to be **very** fragile and id be suspicious of cross browser compatibility. A better solution would be to add a class or data attribute to each component to create a distinct scope for each component and then use a single jquery/dom operation at the end to do all the things you need. It looks like right now you are just trying to format data. So this could be simple.

```
<p>Price:
  <span data-format="currency">5</span>
</p>
```

Then a single script at the bottom of the page that handles `data-format="currency"`. This is trivial with jquery or just js.

```
(() => {
  const format = (value) => {
    return value.toLocaleString('en-US', {
      style: 'currency',
      currency: 'USD',
    });
  };
  
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-format="currency"]');
  
  elements.forEach((el) => {
    const value = Number(el.innerText);

    if (!isNaN(value)) {
      el.innerText = format(value);
    }
  })
})();
```

The `data-format="currency"` can be added anywhere and it will try to format the value as currency.

If you think you might need to create a bunch of formats, you can abstract a bunch of the looping and selecting logic away into a helper function.

```js
const format = (type, formatter) => {
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-format="${type}"]`);

  elements.forEach((el) => {
    el.innerText = formatter(el.innerText);
  })
};

format('currency', (text) => {
  let result = text;
  const value = Number(text);

  if (!isNaN(value)) {
    result = value.toLocaleString('en-US', {
      style: 'currency',
      currency: 'USD',
    });
  }

  return result;
});

format('number', (text) => {
  let result = text;
  const value = Number(text);

  if (!isNaN(value)) {
    result = value.toLocaleString('en-US');
  }

  return result;
});
```

```html
<p data-format="currency">10</p>
<p data-format="number">1924</p>
```

Comment: Nice answer, good to point out what a bad idea this approach is and give a better approach; two things: (1) You ought to take your jsfiddle and put it right here in your answer as a stack-snippet, and (2) I'm curious why choose `data-format` instead of `class="currency"`? (I use classes to mark what a thing _**is**_ — in fact, I could see doing `<span class="currency" data-format="USD">5</span>`)

Comment: I typically stay away from classes for js bindings as it's not as semantic, it's not clear from classnames what the intention is. I've had people remove worthless class names and end up breaking something since they had no idea it was a binding especially since it had no attached style. And now nobody wants to remove classnames. In this case itd be pretty obvious if you had a currency class but if your using data attributes for other things you should be consistent.